# Постраничная навигация и GetList. GetList сразу же выбирает все данные или запрос выполняется при первом вызове Fetch()?

Tags: битрикс, выборка, постраничный-вывод

Вопрос про то, как работает выборка в Bitrix. 
Сначала GetList выбирает ВСЕ данные, а NavStart - уже позволяет получить конкретную страницу? 
Или GetList просто подготавливает запрос, а сама выборка происходит при первом вызове Fetch() ?

Буду благодарен, если укажете, где про это можно почитать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`GetList` это обращение к базе по параметрам, а 4 параметр `arNavStartParams` этой функции позволяет ограничивать выборку согласно текущей постраничной навигации.

В `GetList` мы получается лишних данных не получаем — они отфильтровываются количеством, текущей страницей  и т.д.

Comment: А если мы вызываем GetList, и в NavStartParams передаем только размер страницы, будет ли выборка выбирать все записи или нет ?

Comment: Я проверил. Насколько я вижу, когда мы вызываем GetList, то mysql_query уже выполняется. То есть если мы не зададим у функции GetList, как Вы сказали, данные о том, какую страницу мы выбираем, то выберется весь объем данных.

Comment: Получается GetList() с параметром iNumPage лучше, чем GetList с пустым параметром arNavStartParams и потом отдельно вызванным NavStart().

Comment: Всё верно. Вы не отфильтровываете в PHP результаты